# Should I use curl to consume my own api?

Tags: php, software-design, saas

I am building a web application that will power several of my clients websites. It also involves a rest API. Would it be wise to have my clients' PHP websites use curl consume the API instead of directly calling the PHP code I have. I have been told it would make it easier for deployment especially for clients whose websites aren't on my server but I don't see the benefit. Also I have been told that it would help protect our code, again I don't see the benefits of that as the client would only have access to the base active-record models. 
I don't have a problem with using curl. My issue sis that at the moment all my clients websites are hosted on my server I don't think it's efficient to have a request come to the server only to have the server send a curl  request to itself to fill that request.
Any opinion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to create a system where you also consume your own API. Such solution is scalable and you ensure that potential clients will use standardized API that you also use. However, as you might have noticed, it's more of a design question rather than direct programming question so it might be closed due to being offtopic.

Comment: Similar Programmers.SE: [Should I use my own public API for my web interface?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/302028/should-i-use-my-own-public-api-for-my-web-interface)

Comment: Curl is good, what might be even better is providing your clients with a wrapper library around the API calls. That way users don't have to know about the mechanics of the API and if you ever have to make breaking changes, you may be able to update the wrapper as opposed to having all clients change the code that depends on your API.

Comment: I don't have a problem with using curl. My issue sis that at the moment all my clients websites are hosted on my server I don't think it's efficient to have a request come to the server only to have the server send a curl  request to itself to fill that request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a fine model, even if you do get the overhead of calling PHP twice. That overhead is real!

However, one alternative is that if your API works well and you have correctly built it with request/response objects (instead of relying directly on globals, superglobals, php://input, header() etc), then you can also create a 'fake HTTP client' that just calls the same PHP code locally.

Comment: So essentially, my clients' websites should be able to use local code and if that isn't available it call the API?

Comment: No I'm saying that from the perspective of the client's website it should look and feel like a HTTP request, while in reality you mock request/response objects that 'pretend' to make a HTTP request but in reality set up your API source and do a local call.

Comment: If this makes no sense to you, just do real HTTP requests and comment here in a year when you are getting performance problems ;)

Comment: I get you, but what if the client's website is not on my server wouldn't I need to give them the code base for my API?

Comment: If there's an actual physical separation between front and backend, then what other choice do you have?

Comment: In some cases there will be in others there won't be. If possible I wouldn't want the apps with no separation to suffer the inefficiency unnecessarily.

Comment: Well then my suggestion totally works. As long as your 'RealHttpClient' and 'FakeLocalHttp" client are interchangable, you don't suffer the overhead if it is locally. Just make sure you design your API with a proper, modern framework and then you will have that option in the future, and you can start by just doing plain http requests.